# Path connectedness of the complement of countable set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be an open (path) connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a nonconstant anlytic function

I proved that the subspace topology on $f^{-1}(0)$ is discrete and $f^{-1}(0)$ is countable.

How do I conclude that $G\setminus f^{-1}(0)$ is (path) connected?

It is easy for the case $G=\mathbb{C}$, but in general it does not seem easy to prove

Comment: You do want to assume $f$ is not constant.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh right edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two points $a, b \in G \backslash f^{-1}(0)$, start with the straight line segment joining them.  This may contain points of $f^{-1}(0)$, but only finitely many.  Make a sufficiently small semicircular detour around each of them.

Comment: Why does it contain only finitely many zeros??

Comment: Aha it's because $[0,1]$ is compact

Comment: I presume you mean a path composed of straight line segments? $G$ is not necessarily convex...

Comment: @copper.hat Isn't it possible because zeros are isolated?

Comment: Take $G = \{z | |z|>1\}$ and $a=2, b=-2$. The straight line joining them doesn't lie in $G$. It is a nitpick.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm sure he meant polygonal lines.

Comment: @Rubertos: I am certain he did, I was just pointing out the omission...

Comment: Actually if $G$ is open and connected and $E\subset G$ is countable, then $G\setminus E$ is path connected. (The point being $E$ could be wild - dense in $G$ for example - compared with the zero set of an analytic function).