# Connectedness of complements

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ are compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $B=A \cup$ iso($B$). 
If $A^c$ is connected then prove that

$B^c$ is connected.

Here iso($B$) denotes the set of isolated points of $B$.

For a compact subset $A$ of $\mathbb{C}$ we say that $A^c$ is connected if $A^c$ does not have any bounded component.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have taken complements on both sides and we get, $B^c=A^c \cap (iso(B))^c$. Now $(iso(B))^c$ is connected and $A^c$ is connected. Then how can we say their intersection is also connected.

Comment: @ManuRohilla Put that in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A^c$ is an open connected set of $\mathbb C$, it is path connected. The set of isolated points is always countable in $\mathbb R^n$[Proof: $\mathbb R^n$ is second countable. Subspaces of second countable spaces are countable. An uncountable set consisting of isolated points only is not second countable.] Now $B^c$ is equal to $A^c$ minus countably many points. Can you conclude that $B^c$ is path connected using [Why is open connected minus countable set is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471004/why-is-open-connected-minus-countable-set-is-connected)?

Comment: How can we say that if $B$ is compact then isolated points of $B$ are finite.

Comment: @ManuRohilla I deleted my previous comment (since it is very wrong! E.g. $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is an infinite set consisting of isolated points only) and make a significant edit, please check out.